# Flue gas scrubbing in water

Tags: thermodynamics

What happens if we dip flue gas in water? Flue gas will primarily contain nitrogen and carbon dioxide. Will they escape water without condensing. The water may be slightly higher than room temperature. Pressure is standard atmospheric pressure.

On a related note, what happens if carbon monoxide and methane are dissolved in water?

Comment: Have you tried? Measure the constituents before the water and after. What differences do you find? Often done when testing engines… may be worth checking.

Comment: off the cuff guess, at least some carbon dioxide will go into solution... until the solution becomes saturated and can take no more.

Comment: Common technology you can look up.  Often done with lime in the water to absorb CO2. SO2 is also common in flue gas. The flue gas will be hot, not cool, to prevent condensation of carbonic and sulfurous acids .